# Seaborn heatmap re-indexing not working properly?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I've been recently working with Pandas-based heatmaps (using Seaborn for plotting). My current script is as follows:

```
df = dataframe.pivot("A","B","C")
df.index = pd.CategoricalIndex(df.index,categories=["c1","c2"...some custom categories...])
df.sort_index(0,inplace=True)
sns.heatmap(df).
```

This setting does not change heatmap's ordering as defined in step 2. How does one achieve that?

Thank you!

EDIT: actually, it changes the row order in df, yet heatmap looks the same.

Minimal example:

```
A = pd.DataFrame([("a","b",1),("c","c",1),("a","a",1),("b","c",1),("a","c",1)])
df  =  A.pivot(0,1,2)
df.index = pd.CategoricalIndex(df.index,categories=["b","a","c"])
df.sort_index(0,inplace=True)
sns.heatmap(df)
plt.show()
```

Column and row order is the same, I would wish for "b a c".

EDIT 2: It seems that y-axis order changed correctly, yet x-axis remains the same, even if sort_index(1) is used.
[image]

Comment: What is "step 2"?

Comment: df.index = pd.CategoricalIndex(df.index,categories=["c1","c2"...some custom categories...])

Comment: Can you provide a small example dataframe?

Comment: Example added. Is it clear?

Comment: This seems to work for me. The index is reordered and the plotted heatmap shows this. If you want to reorder columns also, you need to apply it to the columns as well.

Comment: And how does one achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the same concept to your columns:

```
...
df.columns = pd.CategoricalIndex(df.columns,categories=["b","a","c"])
df.sort_index(1,inplace=True)
sns.heatmap(df)
```

Comment: Perfect. Apparently I was not aware of the "columns" concept. (facepalm)

Comment: Pandas doesn't make it easy with index (rows) and columns being `Index` objects!